# How to handle in Rails an image from api generated by Microsoft ImageHttpHandler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm trying to solve an issue.
I must get images from a Microsoft webservice. I'm using HTTParty in my project, but when I get the data the result is:

```
"\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01,\x00\x00\x01,\b\x06\x00\x00\x00y}\x8Eu\x00\x00\x00\x01sRGB\x00\xAE\xCE\x1C\xE9\x00\x00\x00\x04gAMA\x00\x00\xB1\x8F\v\xFCa\x05\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0E\xC3\x00\x00\x0E\xC3\x01\xC7o\xA8d\x00\x00\xEBAIDATx^\xEC\xFD\x87wTW\xB6-\x0E\xBF\x7F\xE07\xBE\xF1\xEE\xBB\xB7\xFBvn\xB7\xDDng\xB7sN`\xB0\xC1\xE4\x9Cs\x8E6\xD1\xD8\xC6&\xE7dr\xCE\x19\x91\x84\x90\x90\x04\x02\x84@9\xE7\x9C\x11( \x913\xEB\x9Bs\xEF\xDA\xAA\xA3B\x98T\x02A\x9F\xEDq,!U\x9D*\xEDS5k\xAD\xB9\xE6\x9A\xEB\xFF\x9C9sF.]\xBAd\x1F\xF6\x1E\xD8\xAF\x01\xFB5P\xAB_\x03\xC4\xAA\xFFs\xF5\xEAU\xB1\x97\xBD\x03\xF6\x0E\xD8;P\xDBw\x80X\xF5\x7F\x18]\xD9\xEB\xF1\xEE\xC0\xAD[\xB7?\xFE\xCD\x9B7\xE4\xE6\xCD\x9B8\xF8\x15\xC7\xAD\er\xEB\xD6\xCD{|\xA2\xB7\x84\xFF\xD9\xCB\xDE\x81\xA7i\a\x88U6`\xD5\x82+z\xFD\xFAU\xA9\xA8(\x93\x82\x82\x1CIK\x8B\x97\xB8\xB80\x89\x8A\x0E\x96\xE8\x98\x10\x89\x89\r\x97X\x1Cqq\x11\x12\x1F\x1F)I\xC91\x92\x9E\x9E(9\xB9ir\xEAT\xBE\x94W\x94\xC8\xE5\xCB\x17\xEE\x03\xCCj\xC1\x1Fl?\x05{\a\x1E`\al\xC0z\x80Ms\xE7]\xAE\\\xB9D\xAEB`\x82", @response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @headers={"cache-control"=>["private"], "content-type"=>["image/jpeg"], "server"=>["Microsoft-IIS/7.5"], "x-aspnet-version"=>["4.0.30319"], "x-powered-by"=>["ASP.NET"], "date"=>["Wed, 23 Dec 2015 13:38:31 GMT"], "connection"=>["close"], "content-length"=>["60332"]}
```

I try to pass this data to Carrierwave using remote_model_url but of course is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Tempfile`:

```
response = HTTParty.get('http://i.imgur.com/2xYuR0B.jpg')
ext = '.' + response.content_type.split('/').last
tmp = Tempfile.new(['img', ext])
tmp.binmode
tmp.write(response.body)
```

Now you can pass `tmp` to Carrierwave, for example:

```
u = User.new
u.avatar = tmp
u.save!
u.avatar.url # => "/uploads/tmp/1450886065-1021-6429/img20151223-1021-1w0uu5b.jpeg"
```